# how can I automaticly create a variable and assign the value from a line in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file that contains the following lines

```
date=2019-05-21;time=11:23:00;logid="0000000015";type="traffic";subtype=" forward";level="notice";vd="BE-FW";eventtime=x;srcip=x.x.1.36;srcport=34640;srcintf="xss";srcintfrole="undefined";dstip=x.x.3.101;dstport=443;dstintf="sss";dstintfrole="undefined";poluuid="45a8fbae-de85-51e8-a624-09620d3722dd";sessionid=258597994;proto=6;action="start";policyid=10;policytype="policy";service="HTTPS";dstcountry="Reserved";srccountry="Reserved";trandisp="noop";duration=0;sentbyte=0;rcvdbyte=0;sentpkt=0;appcat="unscanned"
```

How can I collect these values automaticly and assign them to a variable.
f.e:
`date=2019-05-21`
`time=11:23:00`
`logid="0000000015"`
`type="traffic"`
`subtype=" forward"`
`level="notice"`
....

Comment: For good practice consider using a dictionary structure instead (`dict()`).

Answer (score 0):

To programatically create variables from a given file, you can perform an `exec` on each line inside the file, however you may need to edit the file and wrap each assignment in quotes for it to work e.g;

```
date=2019-05-21;time=11:23:00;   ==>   date="2019-05-21";time="11:23:00";
```

And to perform the exec:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
  variables = f.read()
  variables = variables.split(';')

for variable in variables:
  exec(variable)

print(time)

> 11:23:00
```

Be careful while using `exec()` if you allow users to input a value using `exec(input())`, the user may issue commands to change file or even delete all the files using command `os.system('rm -rf *')`. So you need to be 100% sure that what you have in the file is safe to use with `exec()`